# Java how to check float minus float is integer?

Tags: java, spring

For example, float a is 2.15, float b is 1.15, but `a-b` will be `1.0000001`,

My first question is how to get the right answer `2.15-1.15=1`?

My second question is how to check the result of a minus b is an integer?

Comment: To get the precise answer use BigDecimal, if you are working the money use BigDecimal. Note that BigDecimal can be a bit slower, so depending on the nature of your calculations you may want to avoid it, because in most cases an imprecise float/double is more than suitable when rounding is applied where necessary for the final output/display.

Comment: You can only check whether `a - b` is *close* to an integer, if you use `float` or `double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can either still using float and round the result, or use double instead.
2. If you mean the result has no fraction (decimal part) you can check with `% 1 == 0`. It should give you true.

Something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      double x = 2.15;
      double y = 1.15;
      double z = x - y;

      System.out.println("Sum of x-y = " + z);
      System.out.println("Sum of x-y = " + Math.round(z));
      System.out.println("Sum of x-y = " + (z % 1 == 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> For example, float a is 2.15, float b is 1.15.

Wrong. That's not possible.

A `float` value is defined to be 32 bits large. That's a problem - basic mathematics: A 32-bit value can only contain 2^32 different possible values. That's about 4 billion. I know for a fact that there are far more than 4 billion numbers between 0 and 1 (in fact, there are an infinite amount of numbers). Let alone how many numbers exist between positive and negative infinity!

So how does this work? Is your computer a magic voodoo god that breaks the universe? No, of course not. Instead, only a bit less than 4 billion numbers are representable as a `float` and all other numbers **simply are not**. Imagine the number line drawn out on a big board. Somebody tossed 4 billion darts at this thing, made a picture, and decreed: Only the darts are what you can store with a `float` value. Anything in between 2 darts? Tough luck. **Not representable**.

2.15, 1.15? **No dart**. There is a dart really close to 2.15, and also one really really close to 1.15, though.

The rules of `float` math are as follows: If the result of any mathematical operation is not a 'dart number', then it is **silently rounded** to the nearest dart.

The darts are not linearly distributed. There are many, many darts around 0 and 1. In fact, about as many darts are between 0 and 1 as there are darts above 1. As you get away from 0, there are fewer and fewer darts. Eventually (around 2^26 or so), the distance between 2 darts is **more than 1**, meaning, `reallyLargeFloat + 1 == reallyLargeFloat` is **true**!! (because it is rounded to the nearest dart, which is the same dart).

The problem with 2.15-1.15 is: The actual thing that happens is:

- Find the dart nearest 2.15. Let's say its 2.1500001.
- Find the dart nearest 1.15. Let's say 1.149999999999998.
- Calculate 2.1500001 - 1.149999999999998. Then take the result and round *that* to the nearest dart.
- That happens to end up being 1.0000001.

You can't ask the system 'not to do the rounding silliness'. Because the universe and math and all that: 32-bits are what they are.

Thus, a few conclusions:

- Any time you do an equality check on any result of math on `double` or `float,` you really shouldn't do that, instead, do an 'epsilon compare': Is the difference between the 2 below some really tiny number? If yes, let's call them equal. So, don't do `a - b == 1.0`, do: `Math.abs(a - b) - 1.0 < 0.00001`. Yes, this is annoying.
- If you require precision, **do not use `float` or `double`**. Instead, use ints/longs (e.g. if storing an amount in EU currency, do not store, say, `5.25` for something that costs 5 euros and 25 cents. Store `525` - the amount in cents. In a `long`. Or, use `BigDecimal`, but that is a very complicated tool that has a steep learning curve.
- If you want to know where the darts are, write down 1/3 in decimal notation. You can't: It's 0.3333 endlessly repeating. Computers count in binary (base 2), not decimal (base 10). A computer counts: 0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, etcetera. For this reason, various things that 'work' in decimal, such as, say, 3/10ths (0.3 in decimal), would have infinite digits (just like 1/3 does) in binary. This should hopefully help that it is really difficult to reason about where they are. [Read up on IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which describes the way its done, if you want to know the details.

Answer (score 1):

The first question as covered in comments has an answer here [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). To get the precise answer you can use BigDecimal, or work in Integer units of 100's or 1000's to suit your needs eg 215-115 = 100.

For your second question you can call `Integer.parseInt(float)`, and as long as a `NumberFormatException` is not thrown, then you know it was a valid Integer. You could do it a bit like this with a helper method:

```
float a = 2.15f;
float b = 1.15f;
float result = a-b;

System.out.println(isValidInteger(result));

//Helper method to check if the number is a valid integer
public static boolean isValidInteger(float number) {
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(number+"");
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hint: The result will always be false. If you want to get an integer from a float then use rounding with a tolerance as shown in the linked question.